# jQuery / Validate - different error/success highlight rule for checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Right now my form is working perfectly using the following rules to add a label with either a green tick mark or red error message to the right of my form input:

```
highlight: function(label) {
            $(label).closest('.form-element').addClass('error')
            .closest('.form-element').removeClass('success');;
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label
            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.form-element').addClass('success');
        },
```

And the relevant CSS is:

```
#jqvForm label.valid {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url("../images/tick.png") center center no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999em !important;
  position: absolute;
}
#jqvForm label.error {
  color: red;
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

However - I have one checkbox on the page where the user must agree to the terms & conditions.  Putting the error message or tick mark next to it looks really bad.

Is there a way with validate to set a different highlight / success function for a checkbox?  Or am I better off not using validate to this one box and instead just using something else to make sure the box is checked?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful input.  Where someone has helped or pointed me in the right direction I've marked answers as accepted.  If not then I've gone back to document the solution I found to the problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

from the [options documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)  it says override highlight to decide which fields and how to highlight, so if your t+c checkbox has a class 'myCheckbox' you could do something like this

```
success: function (label) {
    if (label.hasClass('myCheckbox')) {
        // do something with the checkbox
    }
    else {
        // do something with other fields
    }
},
highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    var v = $(element);
    if (v.hasClass('myCheckbox')) {
        // do something with the checkbox
    }
    else {
        // do something with other fields
    }
}
```